# how can i search in whole project by phpstorm whenthe project is on the server?

Tags: search, project, phpstorm

i need to access the whole online project by phpstorm to patch the project or search in the whole project etc.. is it possible by phpstorm?

Comment: You can search trough local files only -- you cannot search if your project files are located on FTP. Sure -- you can download the project first and then search trough it -- if this is OK then [lease check http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/

Answer (score 2):

Try Shift+Cmd+F? Or, you can press Shift+Cmd+A, and type in 'search', then you will see a list of actions you can choose from.

Comment: thanks for your response but its not my issue, i need to access my project that is on the server not local project.
may be in tools -> deployment i can access to my online project but i don't know how to config it.. and don't know then i can search in my whole project or not..